# Make data editable from the persistent local storage

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm creating a shiny app with local persistent data referred from [Dean Attali blog](https://deanattali.com/blog/shiny-persistent-data-storage/#mysql) as in section: 1. Local file system (local).

My query is, is it possible to make the data editable and reload from local drive?

***aggregates data from inputs***

```
formData <- reactive({
    #data <- sapply(fieldsMandatory, function(x) input[[x]])
    formdata <- c("Associate Name" = input$aname,"Client Name" = input$cname,"Project"=input$project,
                  "Associate Client Email"=input$cemail,
                  "Ask By Customer"=input$ask,"Project Type"=input$type,"Billing"=input$bill,"Remarks"=input$rem ,
                  "Completion Date" = as.character(input$date), "Website status" = input$status )
    formdata <- t(formdata)
    formdata
  })
```

***saves data to csv*** (this creates a separate file every time we submit)

```
saveData <- function(formdata) {
    fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv",
                        humanTime(),
                        digest::digest(formdata))

    write.csv(x = formdata, file = file.path(responsesDir, fileName),
              row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
}
```

***loads the data*** (Binding all csv's which contains responses)

```
Data <- reactive( {
    # Read all the files into a list
    files <- list.files(responsesDir, full.names = TRUE)
    data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
    data <- do.call(rbind, data)
    return(data) 
}
```

***displaying data in a table***

```
output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
    Data()
})
```

I would like to know if we could make a single CSV file while saving the inputs from the form and make it editable to update values. My biggest hardship is the save function which creates a separate CSV file when we submit the form that complexes to fetch a specific row to edit.

UI that displays the data

```
DT::DTOutput("responses"),style = "height:auto; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"),
```

**Any help would be really grateful**